# Use Pixel watch as Heartrate monitor for phone apps?

Tags: android-wear, fitness, google-fit

I have a Pixel watch and a Samsung S22 Ultra.

I want to use the Pixel watch as a heart rate monitor source for an app on my phone.. however, when I try to pick a heart rate source the watch doesn't show up.

Every web search I do talks about tracking the activity using a watch app.. but i don't want to do this, because it kills the already abysmal battery life.

Is there some way to use the Pixel watch as a connected heart monitor only?